# Create a loop to stationarise data

Tags: python

My problem is: 
Currently my code runs the dickey fuller test and differences the data if the p-value is greater than 0.05, but I need it to re-run the dickey-fuller test again and difference the data again if the p-value is still greater than 0.05, and continue doing so until the condition that the p-value is less than 0.05 is satisfied

I have a dataframe of time series data.  In order to determine whether it is stationary, I have performed the dickey fuller test using the following code:

```
print("Results of Dickey Fuller Test")
dftest=adfuller(df['I'],autolag='AIC' )
dfoutput=pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test statistic', 'p-value', '# Lags    Used', 'Number of Observations Used'])
for key, value in dftest[4].items():
dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)' %key ]=value
```

In the Dickey Fuller test, if the p-value is greater than 0.05 this means the data is not stationary and the data can be differenced to make it stationary. 
I want to create a loop such that the dickey-fuller test is run and if the p-value is greater than 0.05, then the data is differenced and this continues until the p-value is less than 0.05.

This is what I have written so far:

```
if dfoutput['p-value']>0.05:
   df.diff()
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? What are you asking?

Comment: I want to create a loop such that the dickey-fuller test is run and if the p-value is greater than 0.05, then the data is differenced and this continues until the p-value is less than 0.05.

Comment: Currently my code differences the data if the p-value is greater than 0.05, but I need it to re-run the dickey-fuller test again and difference the data again if the p-value is still greater than 0.05, and continue doing so until the condition that the p-value is less than 0.05 is satisfied

Comment: Do you know about the `while` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check up on while loops and do-while loops in general, not just python. You want the loop to continue forever until the diff results in a test < 0.05.

```
dftest=adfuller(df['I'], autolag='AIC')
while True:
    dfoutput=pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test statistic', 'p-value', '# Lags    Used', 'Number of Observations Used'])
    if dfoutput['p-value'] > 0.05:
        df.diff()
    else:
        break
```

What if it's exactly 0.05?

Further reading on [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=while%20loop#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).